# Getting 401 - Unauthorized error while calling .Net Core 2.2 API which is secured by Identity Server 3

Tags: oauth-2.0, .net-core, identityserver3

For my mobile app I am trying to create a secured API. I have created an oAuth server with Identity server 3 using ResourceOwner Flow. The token is successful generated. But whenever I am calling my protected API I am receiving 401-unauthorized error.

Below code at OAuth server

```
`var defaultmobileClient = new Client
                {

                    ClientId = "iqimplicit",
                    ClientName = "iqimplicit",
                    Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
                    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
                    IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,//default value is 5 minutes this is the token that allows a user to login should only be used once
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 3600, // default is one hour access token is used for securing routes and access to api in IQ
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RequireSignOutPrompt = true,
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("mysecret".Sha256())
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        Core.Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        Core.Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        Core.Constants.StandardScopes.Email,                           
                        Core.Constants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
                    },
                    ClientUri = "https://localhost:44300/",                     
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>(),
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        "https://localhost:44300/"
                    },
                    LogoutSessionRequired = true
                };`
```

.Netcore api Startup looks as below

```
`public class Startup
 {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44300/ids";
            options.ApiName = "iqimplicit";
            options.ApiSecret = "mysecret";

        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "SGPAY WebApi", Version = "v1" });

        });
        services.Configure<IdentityAppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("IdentitySettings"));

        services.AddDbContext<SGPAYDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SGPAYDatabase")));
        RegisterDependencies.Register(services);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SGPAY WebApi V1");
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}`
```

The controller looks as as below:

```
`namespace Test
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/Test
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {          
        return Ok(new LoginUser {UserName ="Test", Password="User" });
    }

    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    // GET: api/Test/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
}`
```

while calling http://localhost:2305/api/Test I should get 200 response. But I am getting 401-unauthorized error.

Comment: IS3 might be authorizing your entire client even though you do not have a `[Authorize]` header on your GET. Try adding `[AllowAnonymous]` on your get. Or since you have two GET calls it might be confused and not knowing how to resolve your GET request and falling back to the `[Authorized]` GET.

Comment: First Get is Non Authorized as [Authorize] is given only on second get.  I am able to access first get without any token i.e. just by giving the url 'api/Test' but getting 401 for 'api/Test/5'. I think there is some setting issue either the oAuth Server configuration or Resource Server configuration.

Comment: Well that sounds like it is working, what does your API call look like? Are you passing in your Client name and secret in the request?

Comment: I am only passing bearer token while calling the authorized api
`GET /api/Test/5 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50501
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ.......
Cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d6c72441-4f64-4bf7-9e41-c45326d86c97`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your controller instead of using `[Authorize]` use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

You will need to register the bearer authorization in your startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44300/ids",
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = "iqimplict";
        });
```

This example is for IS4 so you might need to tweak it slightly to meet your need. But the main thing is you need to register your bearer authentication for your controller.

Comment: Thank Hasemeyer, it is working now with couple of tweaks. I had to remove the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from get method attribute and changed the value of options.Audience="https://localhost:44300/ids/resource". I was great help from you.